# Continue after Try has failed

Tags: python, django, loops, try-except

I have a function:

```
def save_to_models(all_item_tags):
    from article.models import Articles    
    for item in all_item_tags:
        newobj = Articles()
        try:
            newobj.pub_date    =item.contents[9].contents[0]
        except:
            continue
        try:
            newobj.title       =item.contents[1].contents[0]
        except:
            continue    
        try:   
            newobj.description =item.contents[5].contents[0]
        except:
            continue
        try:
            newobj.image       =get_the_picture(item.contents[7])
        except:
            continue

        newobj.save()
```

each model has `unique=True` so I'm using try, except to skip over the error I get when its trying to input a data that's already in the database. How can I condense this code? I feel like its a lot of unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: For one thing, [*don't use bare `except`*](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/) - be specific about what could go wrong. For another, if you want to suppress errors for a line and you're using Python 3.4+, see [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress). Also, aligning whitespace like that is not a great idea.

Comment: The *unique error* is raised when you try to **save** a duplicate object. So, no need for all those `try...except` clauses. Just move `newobj.save()` inside a `try...except` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Django is smart: like stated in one of the comments, it's only gonna raise an error when the *save()* method is called. Until then, `Article` is a normal Python object. What you should would look more like this :

```
from psycopg2 import IntegrityError # this is the actual error raised by psycopg2 (the postgres python driver)

from article.models import Articles

for item in all_item_tags:
    try:
        new_article = Articles(
            pub_date=item.contents[9].contents[0],        
            title=item.contents[1].contents[0],
            description=item.contents[5].contents[0],
            image=get_the_picture(item.contents[7])

        new_article.save() # this is where the actual save happens
    except IntegrityError:
        # Handle the exception here
```

Another (more advanced) option is to override the `save()` method and put your logic there.

That said, you could also use `get_or_created` to do that. It looks like this:

```
for item in all_item_tags:
    # this methods returns a boolean True of False if the object is already in the DB.
    # use your unique identifier here
    article, created = Article.objects.get_or_create(unique_id=...)

    # You can then do a classic if-else without handling any errors...
    if created: 
        # Great! The object a
    else:
        # the object exist, do something with it or not...
```

However, there are a few things I would suggest. My feeling is that you are diving into Django without really knowing Python. Django is a big beast that makes a lot of things really convenient (almost *magical*) but it's still Python. If you dive too deep and something breaks, it will be very hard for you to know what's going on. I would suggest furthering your knowledge of Python (it's an amazing language so it's gonna be fun) and then go back to Django or maybe start with a smaller framework like Flask which does less magic! For now, here's a link to the official doc on error handling so you can learn a bit more about it. Also, Django has really good [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/) so I would first look there if a problem arises.

Cheers and happy coding!